# how to restart clone the div input fields ids when it will be deleted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i have a div,in that div I have two input fields like this:

```
<button type = "button" id = "add-botton" >Add Element </button>
  <div id = "trace-div1" class = "trace">
     <h4><span>Trace 1</span></h4>
        <form>
             <table>
                  <tbody>
                      <tr>
                           <td><label>X Axis:  </label></td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="t_x_axis" class = 
                                 "t_x_axis" id="x_axis_t1" size="50"></td>                                              
                      </tr>                                                                             
                      <tr>
                        <td><label>Y Axis:  </label></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="t_y_axis" class ="t_y_axis" 
                                 id="y_axis_t1" size="50"></td>
                        <td><button type = "button" name = "update-button-trace" 
                             class= "update-trace" id = "update-botton-trace1" 
                                 onclick="updatebtn(this)">Update </button></td>
 <button type = "button" name = "delete-button-trace" class="delete-trace" id = "delete-button-trace1" onclick="deletebtn(this)">Delete </button></td>
                    </tr>
                 </tbody>
             </table>
         </form>    
     </div>
```

I am cloning like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add-botton').click(function(){
             var $div = $('div[id^="trace-div"]:last');
             var num = parseInt( $div.prop("id").match(/\d+/g), 10 ) +1;
             var $trace1div = $div.clone(true).prop('id', 'trace-div'+num );
             $trace1div.find('span').text('Trace ' + num);
             $trace1div.find("input[name='t_x_axis']").attr("id", 
               "x_axis_t"+num).val("");
            $trace1div.find("input[name='t_y_axis']").attr("id", 
               "y_axis_t"+num).val("");
            $trace1div.find("button[name='update-button-trace']").attr("id", 
               "update-button-trace"+num);
           $trace1div.find("button[name='delete-button-trace']").attr("id", 
           "delete-button-trace"+num);
          $div.after( $trace1div);  
     });
});
```

In above code when click the Add Element button it is cloning means it gives multiple input fields with different Ids for each  input,for delete button also coming with diff.Id.

My query is when I add some input fields by clicking the Add Element button  click.

Assume if I add 3 divs by using Add Element button then if I want to delete 2nd div by using delete button that particular 2nd div(two input fields),it will be deleted,then that below div3 don't change,I need to be change that div3 become div2,when I delete div2.

If I delete div6 that below div7 became div6 it should not be as div7 again.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kinda like when you add an element you just loop through all the element when you delete one.

```
function deletebtn(obj) {
  $(obj).closest(".trace").remove();
  cleanIds();
};

function cleanIds() {
  $(".trace").each(function(i,x) {
    $(this).attr("id", "trace-div" + (i+1));
    $("h4 span",this).text("Trace " + (i+1));
    $(this).find("input[name='t_x_axis']").attr("id",
      "x_axis_t" + (i+1));
    $(this).find("input[name='t_y_axis']").attr("id",
      "y_axis_t" + (i+1));
    $(this).find("button[name='update-button-trace']").attr("id",
      "update-button-trace" + (i+1));
    $(this).find("button[name='delete-button-trace']").attr("id",
      "delete-button-trace" + (i+1));
  });
};
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#add-botton').click(function() {
    var $div = $('div[id^="trace-div"]:last');
    var num = parseInt($div.prop("id").match(/\d+/g), 10) + 1;
    var $trace1div = $div.clone(true).prop('id', 'trace-div' + num);
    $trace1div.find('span').text('Trace ' + num);
    $trace1div.find("input[name='t_x_axis']").attr("id",
      "x_axis_t" + num).val("");
    $trace1div.find("input[name='t_y_axis']").attr("id",
      "y_axis_t" + num).val("");
    $trace1div.find("button[name='update-button-trace']").attr("id",
      "update-button-trace" + num);
    $trace1div.find("button[name='delete-button-trace']").attr("id",
      "delete-button-trace" + num);
    $div.after($trace1div);
  });
});

function deletebtn(obj) {
  $(obj).closest(".trace").remove();
  cleanIds();
};

function cleanIds() {
  $(".trace").each(function(i,x) {
    $(this).attr("id", "trace-div" + (i+1));
    $("h4 span",this).text("Trace " + (i+1));
    $(this).find("input[name='t_x_axis']").attr("id",
      "x_axis_t" + (i+1));
    $(this).find("input[name='t_y_axis']").attr("id",
      "y_axis_t" + (i+1));
    $(this).find("button[name='update-button-trace']").attr("id",
      "update-button-trace" + (i+1));
    $(this).find("button[name='delete-button-trace']").attr("id",
      "delete-button-trace" + (i+1));
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="add-botton">Add Element </button>
<div id="trace-div1" class="trace">
  <h4><span>Trace 1</span></h4>
  <form>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><label>X Axis:  </label></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="t_x_axis" class="t_x_axis" id="x_axis_t1" size="50"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label>Y Axis:  </label></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="t_y_axis" class="t_y_axis" id="y_axis_t1" size="50"></td>
          <td><button type="button" name="update-button-trace" class="update-trace" id="update-botton-trace1" onclick="updatebtn(this)">Update </button></td>
          <button type="button" name="delete-button-trace" class="delete-trace" id="delete-button-trace1" onclick="deletebtn(this)">Delete </button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: HI @Carsten Lovbo Andersen ,when I click `Add Element` button those divs are cloning so is there any possible to get those div input fields Id's in `alert` box ,like if click `Add Element` button it will display 2nd div input fields so those input field Id i want to show in alert box ,if i click 3rd time `Add Element` button it will display 3rd div input fields so those input field Id's only  i want to show in alert box ,could you please help me.